# What is the purpose of 'pop' in python?

Tags: python, django

I ended up having to use this in my django app within a ModelForm. Of what I have researched it picks and removes an attribute, but why would we want to ever remove data like this?

```
class SomeView(FormView):

  def get_form_kwargs(self):

    kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['request'] = self.request
    return kwargs

class SomeForm(ModelForm):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ...
  ...
```

I figured out that in this case it makes the function work because the init function isn't expecting that value even though I need it. But this feels kinda hacky, throwing it in a view earlier on and then popping it out so it doesn't cause problems.

Wouldn't we want to just find a more clean way to do this, or is this considered the best way?

Comment: `is this considered the best way?` Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the method `pop` is used to retrieve an item from a list or dictionary while also removing it from memory.

Take the following instance:

```
dictionary = {"hello": "world"}

dictionary.pop("hello") -> "world"

print(dictionary) -> {}
```

In this case, you have retrieved and removed "hello"->"world" from the dictionary.
This can be useful when you only need the value once.

Example:

```
my_list = ["hello", "world"]

while my_list:
    value = my_list.pop()
```

In the code above, we are popping the last value of the array on every iteration until there are no values left. This is much cleaner than having to do the following:

```
my_list = ["hello", "world"]

while my_list:
    value = my_list[-1]
    my_list = my_list[:-1]
```

NOTE:
Before popping, it is important that you check that there is at least an element in the list/dictionary. Otherwise, you will get a `KeyError` exception!

```
if "hello" in dictionary:
    dictionary.pop("hello")

if my_list:
    my_list.pop()
```